# How to write methods that create new jsp pages?

Tags: jsp, servlets, portal

I am working on converting some Access forms to servlets and jsp forms where users can enter observations and submit them to a database. Going forward, I hope to allow the user (specifically, scientists/researchers in the field) to create new forms without someone with coding or jsp experience getting involved.

My thought is that the web portal would include a separate "new form creation" jsp and servlet where the user will enter the number of fields and field names and field types. When submitting this page, a method would be called to create a new table in the database (this part I'm okay with) and a new jsp will be built on the front end. Building a new jsp or dynamic jsp based on user input is the part I'm having trouble creating.

This seems crazy, and I'm curious if this is even feasible or there is a way to dynamically create new pages and forms from the back end. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: This may help, http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=21130&seqNum=4

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to build a solution.

I think it's possible to build that kind of page
but It looks quite dangerous.

If it's built, then any users can create databases or tables
whenever they want.

Anyway,
it seems possible to me to build it
if you give some limitations to that system
such as type of inputs, the number of fields.

The purpose of framework like jsp is to make a site dynamically after all.